# Output does not include the orginal variable name

Tags: r

When I assign numbers to variable using assign function and then using get function, the output does not include the orginal variable name. Here are the details of the problem:

consider

```
z=data.frame(x=c(1,2,3))
```

saving names in data frame.

```
names=names(z)
```

data frame only contains one name.

```
names[1]
```

Now I assign the values of the first column in data frame to the name in data frame.

```
assign(names[1],z[,1])
```

The problem is when I use get function for some test, the output donot include the original name in data frame,

```
shapiro.test(get(names[1]))
```

and what I get as output is:

```
    Shapiro-Wilk normality test
```

data:  get(names[1])

W = 1, p-value = 1

Comment: Thank for explaining, I wil update the post.

Comment: what I actually need is to create variables (with the actual names in data frame) with a loop.

Comment: What is your expected output?  Is the problem the `data:` line that `shapiro.test` shows in its output?  Did you want that line to show `data: z$x`?  `data: x`?  something else?

Comment: I would like to thank you a lot for your help.

Answer (score 4):

### data.frame

This will create a one column data frame for each column in `z`

```
for(nm in names(z)) assign(nm, z[nm])
```

### vector

or either of these this will create a vector for each column in `z`

```
for(nm in names(z)) assign(nm, z[[nm]])

list2env(z, .GlobalEnv)
```

### attach

This will create an entry on the search list that contains a vector for each column in `z` without putting them in the global environment so you can now refer to just `x`.

```
attach(z)
```

You can examine the search list using:

```
search()
```

and detach `z` when finished using:

```
detach("z")
```

### Subscripting

Note that all of the above normally do not represent good programming practice and it is better to just refer to `z$x`, `z[["x"]]` or `z["x"]`  depending on what you want.

### with, within, transform

Another thing you can do is use `with`, `within` or `transform`.  The first one returns a vector equal to `2 * x` and the next two each return a data frame in which x has been doubled.

```
with(z, 2 * x)

within(z, x <- 2 * x)
transform(z, x = 2 * x)
```

### shapiro.test

This will run `shapiro.test` on each column of `z` although the `data:` line in the output won't look so nice

```
lapply(z, shapiro.test)
```

This can alternately be used to force a nicer looking data line (or if you knew there were only one column in `z` then it could be written `my.shapiro.test(names(z), z)` ).

```
my.shapiro.test <- function(nm, z) with(z, do.call("shapiro.test", list(as.name(nm))))
lapply(names(z), my.shapiro.test, z)
```

or one can use the first approach and then fix up the data names afterwards resulting in shorter code but with the disadvantage that it mucks with the internal structure that `shapiro.test` returns.  (If you knew that `z` had only one column then it could be written as `replace(shapiro.test(z[[1]]), "data.name", names(z))`

```
L <- lapply(z, shapiro.test)
for(nm in names(L)) L[[nm]]$data.name <- nm
```

The extra complexities associated with `shapiro.test` are due to the fact that it determines the name using an unevaluated version of the argument.  Most functions in R don't do that (although the tidyverse packages are a notable exception) so you won't have such complexities.

Comment: thanks foe your anwser @ G. Grothendieck, but is there still such way to get over this problem without using with function?

Comment: I want to simple loop throught the varibles in my data frame t do the shapiro.test (while producing the original variable name in the data frame in the output).

Comment: I have tried all the codes, but the wih function is the only way for me to see the the original variable name in the output.

Comment: Because the loops are more flexible thant with function, Maybe in diffrent situation it will be hard to use.

Comment: the basic idea that I dont want to be naming the variables manually, instead I want to use a loop. I tried paste function to create varaible then assign function to assign values. however, the variables orginal names cannot be retreived in the output.

Comment: appreciate your help

Comment: for example, can with function accepts a loop in its second argument instead of shapiro.test.

Comment: and the same apllies to lapply function

Comment: I tried to use paste(c("z",names[1], collapse = "$") but stil have the same problem.

Comment: Also I have triesd:


A=paste(c(names[1],"z"), collapse = "=")
paste0(A,"[,1]")


# and then use:


as.formula(paste0(A,"[,1]"))


but I receive an error

Comment: Error in formula.default(eval(parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE)[[1L]])) : 
  invalid formula

Comment: `shapiro.test(z$x)` will show `z$x` as the data name.  `my.shapiro.test("x", z)` will show `x` as the data name or replace `"x"` with something else if you want something else as the data name.  `my.shapiro.test` is defined in the answer.